# Is it safe to put MySQL queries outside try{ }

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to include database connection in some PHP scripts. So I require() first and then put my queries after. If viewed as a single script, it amounts to something like this:

```
Try {
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}; charset=utf8mb4",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

Catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
// Then I put the queries here
```

It works, but my question is: is this safe? I've seen in most tutorials that they put all the queries within `Try { }` curly brackets. And what is the difference between putting the queries within `Try { }` and putting it after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for whatever reason your query fails the program will crash at the line of code that was executing the query.  There may be justification to do this if this a behavior that you desire in your code, for whatever reason.

Without the error handling your program will just break whenever an error is thrown.  So unless you specifically need to have the query outside of the try catch (I couldn't guess what for), then you will just be creating trouble for yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs during your query (For instance, if it can't execute the query properly because of a missing quote), the error will not be caught and the execution of your script will halt.

Error handling is usually always preferred when possible. If there is a problem fetching data, inserting data, or simply a typo in your query, you should always have a way to notify a user that an error has occurred (And also, log it for further investigation for yourself.)

Comment: Illuminative comments. Now I know that I was very wrong. So how do I put my query within try catch without typing the connection script on every page? For example:
    Include ('connect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

How do I put $sql within the included script? Pardon me; I'm still new to PHP/MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: Don't include it in the `connect.php`. Just use your own try/catch blocks in your code (Outside of `connect.php`), and handle accordingly.